# How to install bootstrap 4 + jquery + popper.js with Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js, angular6

I've installed and updated Angular and Node to the latest version

```
    Angular CLI: 6.0.0
    Node: 8.11.1
    OS: win32 x64
    Angular: 6.0.0
    ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... http, language-service, platform-browser
    ... platform-browser-dynamic, router

     Package                                                                   
     -----------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
    @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
    @angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
    @angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
    @ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
    @schematics/angular               0.6.0
    @schematics/update                0.6.0
    rxjs                              6.1.0
    typescript                        2.7.2
    webpack                           4.6.0
```

Installed Bootstrap 4 via npm and it is working though but dropdowns and modals are not working because jquery and popper.js are not importing the way they used to be in angular 5.

This is what i did: 
Installed the following
        1-  npm install bootstrap@next --save
        2-  npm install jquery --save
        3-  npm install popper.js --save

and added that to angular.json because there is no angular.cli.json

```
     "styles": [   
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
         "styles.css"
      ],
     "scripts": [  
         "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
         "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      ],
```

Comment: If you need jquery just for bootstrap, install ng-bootrap instead

Comment: @David the ng-bootstrap install the lastet of bootstrap ?

Comment: You need to install bootstrap css yourself and ng-bootstrap provide native implementations for bootstrap components (dropdown, modal,...) written with angular without jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont forget to run:

```
npm i tether --save
```

Next in angular.json put the tether path among jquery and bootstrap

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have installed it with Angular 9

```
npm install --save bootstrap jquery popper.js
```